# Do dynamic programming and branch and bound give same result when solving 0/1 knapsack problem?

Tags: time-complexity, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, branch-and-bound

Hi I have a question about knapsack problem and it's algorithms.
I have built some code to solve 0/1 knapsack problem with Dynamic Programming and Branch and Bound.
The value and weight are randomly generated.
I ran the program and obtain the result showing.

Number of Items | Processing Time in milliseconds / Maximun Beneift Val
Number of Items |   Greedy   |   D.P.   |   B. & B.
10        |  0/2502  |    0/2469  |  0/2469
100        |  0/22629  |    8/22621  |  0/19382
1000        |  0/202083  |  651/202081  | 30/173603
10000        |  4/2025662  |66624/2025662  |2709/1637172

So I was wondering if the result of these two algorithms can be different

I am expecting if they are different or just my code is bad

Answer (score 0):

Branch and Bound is just a additional to DP, which mean you can do 0-1 knapsack without Branch and Bound. But, you can apply Branch and Bound when the weight of bag is less that 0. So it's the same algorithm.